# How to disable soft keyboard candidates

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

My application uses GLSurfaceView, receiving data from the soft keyboard via the extended BaseInputConnection. But on certain devices appears the box with word candidates, and app can gets wrong data. Class InputMethodService has method

```
setCandidatesViewShown(boolean shown)
```

but I can not get a reference to current InputMethodService and the documentation says that only the system can interact directly with InputMethodService. Extend InputMethodService - too complicated for this task. Is there a way to disable the candidates in the application?